# Как сделать анимацию без задержек unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу платформер на unity2D и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вобщем я делал анимацию для персанажа. Я написал вот такой код

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
    {
        ani.SetInteger("animashon", 0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 1)
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        ani.SetInteger("animashon", 1);
    }
    else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == -1)
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        ani.SetInteger("animashon", 1);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        ani.SetInteger("animashon", 2);
        Jump();
    }

}
```

Но когда начинается переход анимации на другую то происходит задержка пока анимация не закончится до конца. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробовали создать анимацию через окно `Animation`? Там задержек нету.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, попробей поиграться с остановкой анимации, вот пример(сам начинающий)
Кстати, большинство инфы можно найти на англ сайтах, советую гуглить вначале на англ языке.

using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
Animation anim;

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") &amp;&amp; anim.isPlaying)
    {
        anim.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В Animator'е настроены переходы? Тыкнув на линию перехода можно снять галочку с "Has Exit Time" и анимация перейдет сразу к другой